# how to confirm logged in to pages?

Tags: php

I wonder how to make every pages that need go through login page.  If the person doesn't log in, it will redirect to login page.

I include a function

```
confirm_logged_in();
```

in every page but it keeps asking for the login even after I log in.  Please tell me how to fix that It only needs to log in once but still the keeps people from entering a direct link manually.

I do have session_start(); in every page!

Here the code for login page

```
$username = "";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $required_fields = array("username", "password");
  validate_presences($required_fields);
  if (empty($errors)) {// Attempt Login
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

$found_admin = attempt_login_admin($username, $password);
$found_client = attempt_login_client($username, $password);

if ($found_admin) {
    $_SESSION["admin_id"] = $found_admin["admin_id"];
    $_SESSION["username"] = $found_admin["username"];
    redirect_to("admin.php");
}elseif($found_client){
    $_SESSION["client_id"] = $found_client["client_id"];
    $_SESSION["username"] = $found_client["username"];
    redirect_to("client.php");
} else{// Failure  
    $_SESSION["message"] = "Username/password not found.";
}
}
```

}

Here the code for functions:

```
function redirect_to($new_location) {
  header("Location: " . $new_location);
  exit;
}

function logged_in() {
    return isset($_SESSION['admin_id'] );
}

function confirm_logged_in() {
        if (!logged_in()) {
                redirect_to("login.php");
        }
}

 function find_admin_by_username($username) {
        global $connection;

        $safe_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $username);

        $query  = "SELECT * ";
        $query .= "FROM users ";
        $query .= "WHERE status='admin' ";
        $query .= "AND username = '{$safe_username}' ";
        $query .= "LIMIT 1";

        $admin_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        confirm_query($admin_set);
        if($admin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($admin_set)) {
                return $admin;
        } else {
                return null;
        }
}

function find_client_by_username($username) {
        global $connection;

        $safe_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $username);

        $query  = "SELECT * ";
        $query .= "FROM users ";
        $query .= "WHERE status='client' ";
        $query .= "AND username = '{$safe_username}' ";
        $query .= "LIMIT 1";

        $client_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        confirm_query($client_set);
        if($client = mysqli_fetch_assoc($client_set)) {
                return $client;
        } else {
                return null;
        }
}
function attempt_login_admin($username, $password) {
        $admin = find_admin_by_username($username);
        if ($admin) {
                // found admin, now check password
                if (password_check($password, $admin["hashed_password"])) {
                        // password matches
                        return $admin;
                } else {
                        // password does not match
                        return false;
                }

        } else {
                // admin not found
                return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Well are you setting $_SESSION['admin_id'] when the user logs in? And are you adding session_start(); to all the pages that use this function?

Comment: Because it will always return false if you dont have session_start included in your function.

Comment: How are logging in ?

Comment: I did have session_start()

Comment: Put an `error_log(print_r($_SESSION, true))` in your **logged_in()** function. Make sure that the session vars are what you think they are.. caps issue? misspelled?

Comment: Do you have `session_start` *on every single page you're checking `logged_in`?*

Comment: It's the functions attempt_login_admin() and attempt_login_client(). They return associative arrays and he's trying to test a bool logic in the if-block as if they were variables which returned a bool.

Answer (score 1):

```
$found_admin = attempt_login_admin($username, $password);
$found_client = attempt_login_client($username, $password);

if ($found_admin) {
    $_SESSION["admin_id"] = $found_admin["admin_id"];
    $_SESSION["username"] = $found_admin["username"];
    redirect_to("admin.php");
}elseif($found_client){
    $_SESSION["client_id"] = $found_client["client_id"];
    $_SESSION["username"] = $found_client["username"];
    redirect_to("client.php");
}
```

I don't understand if the functions `attempt_login_admin()` and `attempt_login_client()` return a bool or an array. If you fix that, It should work. You can return a bool in the associative array by assigning the return bool value to `$found_admin['bool']` and verifying the bool in the if-block by `if($found_admin['bool']) { ... }`.

Comment: both attempt_login_admin() and attemp_login_client() return boolean.  I included the functions in the question.

Comment: Then how are you using an associative array on the returned variable?

Comment: $found_admin and $found_client are the variables that hold functions attempt_login_admin() and attempt_login_client() which return true if it matches username and password, false if it doesnt

Comment: Yes, I know. What about using them as an associative array? How can a variable be an array?

Comment: I don't know how to use them as an associative array that will also link to different pages for client and admin.

Comment: Eme your comments dont make sense.